# How to zip an XML file?

Tags: ruby

How can I zip an XML file in Ruby?

For example i have a method:

```
def write_data(data)
  File.open(@filepath,"w") do |f|
    f.write(%[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n])
    f.write(%[<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n])
    f.write(data)
    f.write(%[</urlset>])
    f.close
  end
end
```

The file it creates is an XML file. I want to zip it so that it has a format `test.xml.gz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.open(@filepath, 'w') do |f|
  gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(f)
  gz.write(%[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n])
  gz.write(%[<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n])
  gz.write(data)
  gz.write(%[</urlset>])
  gz.close
end
```

see

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipWriter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can either compress the generated file by executing a shell command `%x(gzip #{@filepath})`, or compress data by [zlib library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib.html) and then write to the file.